# Do I need to set Firebase permissions for db.ref('.info/connected');?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

How do I set up my database rules so that the browser can listen to?

```
var connectedRef = db.ref('.info/connected');
connectedRef.on('value', function(snap) {...});
```

It isn't clear what level I would set to be able to listen to `.info/connected`.

This is my current db rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "service": {
      "$service": {
        "bot": {
          "$bot_id": {
            "notification": {
              "$user_id": {
                ".write": "auth != null"
              }
            },
            "player": {
              ".write": "auth != null",
              ".read": "auth != null"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are your current database rules ?

Comment: @ChintanSoni See above for current database rules. Just added them to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.info/connected` path is a *virtual* node on the client that reflects the socket connection state. It's always available and not affected by security rules.

The same goes for `.info/serverTimeOffset` too.

Comment: Great answer @vzsg!